# LDA and support vector for classification

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I'm using LDA and support vector for classification. And my question is how to preprocess input data? For example: we determine, which eigenvetors of the product of the scatter matrices are responsible for the most variance, and construct a matrix W from them. Then we use this transformation matrix W to project our data on a new space, which we consequently use with support vectors. In the end, when he have a trained model from all of this, do we also need to project our input data onto the new space (multiply it by matrix W)? For example, I'm doing image classification, so I must first resize the image so that it has the same size as every other in the training dataset and then also multiply it by matrix W. And only than I can predict. Sorry in advance if I missed some of the details, I'll add them if needed.

Comment: How can we tell how to preprocess data if we don't know what data there is to process?

Comment: @mathreadler I said that I preprocess images, which are represented as mxn vector, in particular. So if all images in my trainining dataset are 30x30, and the input one is 40x40, i obviously need to scale it, represent as a (900, 1) vector. The question is whether I need to multiply this vector on the above mentioned matrix W